# Is there a strategy to increase the granularity of a deep in the money options contract?

Tags: options, option-strategies

My aim to get as close as possible to a "mini" deep in the money options contract. But mini contracts aren't generally available and buying regular 100 packs of high priced stocks is ridiculously expensive for me. Is there some way to do this using spreads?

Comment: I don't think the product you're looking for exists. In the event I'm mistaken, I'd like to know the answer to this as well. I think part of the issue here is that the deep ITM stuff is sort of niche, and in my case, I'm looking at the longest maturities I can find. I don't think there's going to be anything like a mini, and it's just going to be standard hundreds.

Comment: The only way I can think of is to rollover tight short-dated spreads frequently, adjusting them to whatever the stock price is on that day. You'll get killed on commissions and it's a massive pain in the ass. Although getting killed on commissions might be the lesser evil compared to getting killed on option risk.